# Merge list items based on condition within the list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, merge

I have a list of items :
eg:

```
a = ['IP 123 84', 'apple', 'mercury', 'IP 543 65', 'killer', 'parser', 'goat',
     'IP 549 54 pineapple', 'django', 'python']
```

I want to merge the list items based on condition i.e merge all the items till the item that starts with IP.
The output I want is :

```
a = ['IP 123 84 apple mercury', 'IP 543 65 killer parser goat',
     'IP 549 54 pineapple django python']
```

Please suggest how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generator.

```
def merge(x, key='IP'):
    tmp = []
    for i in x:
        if (i[0:len(key)] == key) and len(tmp):
            yield ' '.join(tmp)
            tmp = []
        tmp.append(i)
    if len(tmp):
        yield ' '.join(tmp)

a = ['IP 123 84','apple','mercury','IP 543 65','killer','parser','goat','IP 549 54 pineapple','django','python']
print list(merge(a))

['IP 123 84 apple mercury', 'IP 543 65 killer parser goat', 'IP 549 54 pineapple django python']
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a fun way to do it:

```
import itertools

def predicate_grouper(li, predicate='IP'):
    indices = [i for i,x in enumerate(li) if x.startswith(predicate)]
    slices = [slice(*x) for x in itertools.zip_longest(indices,indices[1:])]
    for sli in slices:
        yield ' '.join(li[sli])
```

demo:

```
list(predicate_grouper(a))
Out[61]: 
['IP 123 84 apple mercury',
 'IP 543 65 killer parser goat',
 'IP 549 54 pineapple django python']
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.
I'm using Python 2.7 instead itertools.zip_longest() I need to use itertools.izip_longest()

Comment: I think enumerate(a) should be enumerate(li) in the example above

Answer (score 0):

If string 'IP' only exists at the head of some elements of `a`, join the list and then split it:

```
In [99]: ['IP'+i for i in ''.join(a).split('IP')[1:]]
Out[99]: 
['IP 123 84applemercury',
 'IP 543 65killerparsergoat',
 'IP 549 54 pineappledjangopython']
```

If a is like

```
a = ['IP 123 84', 'apple', 'mercury', 'IP 543 65', 'killer', 'parserIP', 'goat',
     'IP 549 54 pineapple', 'django', 'python']                    ^^^^
```

the former solution won't work, you may insert some special sequence (which should never appear in a) to a, and then join & split it:

```
In [11]: for i, v in enumerate(a):
    ...:     if v.startswith('IP'):
    ...:         a[i]='$$$'+v
    ...: ''.join(a).split('$$$')[1:]
Out[11]: 
['IP 123 84applemercury',
 'IP 543 65killerparsergoat',
 'IP 549 54 pineappledjangopython']
```

Comment: What if the `'IP'` was somewhere inside in some of the `a` elements ?

Comment: This will fail if 'IP' is present as a substring. Join the list item till the line should stars with IP.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re    
def group_IP_list(lst):
    groups = []
    word_group = []
    for list_item in lst:
        if re.search(r'^IP',list_item) and word_group:
            groups.append(' '.join(word_group)) 
        elif re.search(r'^IP',list_item):
            word_group = [list_item]
        else: 
            word_group.extend([list_item])
    groups.append(' '.join(word_group)) 
    return groups

#Usage: 
a = ['IP 123 84','apple','mercury','IP 543 65','killer','parser','goat','IP 549 54   pineapple','django','python']
print group_IP_list(a)
#Result:
['IP 123 84 apple mercury', 'IP 123 84 apple mercury killer parser goat', 'IP 123 84 apple mercury killer parser goat django python']
```

Comment: What if the 'IP' was somewhere inside in some of the a elements ?

Comment: That was accounted for.  I'm using regular expressions to search for the beginning of the string (re.search('^IP').  the caret (^) will only match at the beginning of the string; anything else won't match