# Concatenating incomplete setences from lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a list which contains complete and incomplete sentences. The complete sentences are terminated with either `.`, `?`, or `!`. How do I loop through the elements in the list and join incomplete sentences?
For instance,

### Input:

```
myList = ['My first','sentence is incomplete.','Hold on.','Is the second complete?','The third','might not be!','Thanks.','Really appreciate.']
```

### Desired output:

```
myList = ['My first sentence is incomplete.','Hold on.','Is the second complete?','The third might not be!','Thanks','Really appreciate.']
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not as simple as you think it is.

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667697/merge-list-items-based-on-condition-within-the-list

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've tried quite a few suggestions, but I'm getting inconsistent results. If it were simple, I wouldn't ask for help.

Comment: @TheSolider, I posted a solution before I saw the duplicate. As it happens, I'm keeping the solution here because it is a different approach and I'm too lazy to adapt it to the dup.

Comment: @jpp Thanks for the solution. It's quite a different approach to quite a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one brute-force method using `collections.defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList = ['My first','sentence is incomplete.','Hold on.','Is the second complete?',
          'The third','might not be!','Thanks.','Really appreciate.']

d = defaultdict(list)

idx = 0
for j in myList:
    d[idx].append(j)
    if any(j.endswith(k) for k in ('.', '!', '?')):
        idx += 1

sentences = [' '.join(v) for _, v in sorted(d.items())]
```

Result:

```
['My first sentence is incomplete.',
 'Hold on.',
 'Is the second complete?',
 'The third might not be!',
 'Thanks.',
 'Really appreciate.']
```

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation of the incomplete sentences is the easy part, just use the "+" symbol to join the sentences for example, use myList[0]+myList[1]  to get 'My first sentence is incomplete.' You should erase the used elements from the list to not have any problems later. to verify which ones to add, you should use a while loop like this:

```
while (myList!=[]):
    index=0
    if myList[index][-1]=="." or myList[index][-1]=="?" or myList[index][-1]=="!" : #checks if the last element of the string is a . ? or !
        #make a function to concatenate the list elements from myList[0] to myList[index],and delete said elements from the original list, remember to reset index to 0 and repeaat process
```